# How to do a delay on a while loop loop in lua?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm Making something in Lua (I'm new to Lua so I'm not the best) and I was wondering how to Put a 1-second delay on while loop.

I've already tried to put a sleep(1) or a wait(1) but those just still caused the same error (lag)

```lua
local x = 0
while true do 
--execute example code
print(x)
x=x+1
-- put a wait so it waits before doing it again 
end
```

Comment: [Here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction) are some options that might be interesting.

Comment: What is the programming environment or game engine you're working in?  Set corresponding question's tag please.  Is it WOW?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff roblox lmao, I swear im not 2 years old

Comment: What's the intention for this loop?

Answer (score 0):

In Roblox, you can make a loop execute in the background by using 'spawn' to make the code execute in a different thread.

```
local x = 0

-- make it loop in a background thread forever
spawn(function()
    while true do 
        print(x)
        x=x+1
        wait()
    end
end)

print( "I can execute immediately" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while true do 
   print(x)
   x=x+1
   wait(1)
end
```